# How to stop request-params being rewritten in lamda/apiGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

when requesting someting like `/foo?a=1&a=2&a=3`, either API-Gateway or lambda seem to rewrite that url to `/foo?a=1,2,3`. That is unexpected behaviour for my application.

Can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Why? You should see the values in `event.multiValueQueryStringParameters`.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I'd guess the params for `foo` include a string array/List that is intentionally or unintentionally misused, or it's legacy that "can't" be changed. It's possible the value is parsed by the controller as ["1,2,3"], instead of ["1","2","3"].

Comment: Possible or definitely? Can you not update the controller?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I'm not the OP, so no I can't update the controller. I'm simply guessing as to why the OP needs the params in the specific configuration they say they do, since they haven't responded to your comment.

Comment: @computercarguy you are right.. In my specific case I am just a proxy to a different api that expects payload in a specific manner. I have no influence over that. Of course I can rerewrite the URL back to what I assume it was.. But what if the requester really submitted something comma-seperated? From my point of view, apiGateway makes opiniated assumptions about stuff, that isn't specified that way in HTTP